# My application not get started when device started?

Tags: android, boot, autostart

I've written following class to start my application activity `Home.class` but on device start up it shows error **forced close**.

```
public class MyBootRecvr extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Home.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        context.startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Where is my KeyBoard", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

---

**Permissions and receiver tags in application.**

---

```
<receiver
     android:name=".Home"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: i recommend to you read something about Android.

Comment: post your logcat when app is crashing

Comment: when phone starts there is no debugging and no logcat message

Comment: as  imran said please post your logcat so that we can get idea where the error is

Comment: I think as you get forced close so it should be linked with Home.java

Comment: Shouldn't the android:name in the receiver actually refer to .MyBootRecvr?

Comment: how we missed that...........

Comment: thanks buddies you were right my app starts yuppe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the only code in your application, it will never run. Android applications must have at least one subclass of Activity as a starting point for when you run the app. The Activity could should at a minimum look something like this:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.my_layout); /* my_layout should be an XML layout in res/layout */
    }
}
```

Make sure the following code in is your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you create a new Android project in Eclipse, it will do this setting up for you. There are a lot of tutorials on both setting up a basic application in Android, and using Eclipse to do it for you.

Comment: my app do have an activity thats what i am starting from intent

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(context, Home.class);

Comment: first be sure what you're posting

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the application must have an Activity to be launched when you open it. That activity should not be launched via an Intent, rather the intent filters you specify for it (as shown in my answer's AndroidManifest) caused it to be launched automatically. I'm not sure why you're trying to use an intent to manually launch it.

Comment: intent is used there when device start to start activity in background not i front

Answer (score 0):

doing this solve the problem 
thanks to xono

```
<receiver
     android:name=".MyBootRecvr"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```